# Picard-Lindelöf to show whether $u'=u^2-u^3$ has unique solution on an interval

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

This problem is taken from [here](https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2014/06/09/ordinary-differential-equations-stiffness/#05f61f43-dec6-4460-a232-9a7d35f4a218).
Consider the initial value problem:
$$
u'=f(u,t)=u^2-u^3$$
$$ u(0)= 2/a>0 $$
$a$ is a small constant.

> How can I determine wheter a unique solution tom $t=0$ to $t=a$?

**My own attempt/thoughts:**

I know Picard-Lindelöf Theorem is the way to go here, and in order to make a conclusion one has to find Lipschitz constant (and thereby show that $f$ is lipschitz continuous).
So I compute $f_u=2u-3u^2$. I observe that $|f_u|\rightarrow \infty$ as $u\rightarrow\infty$ as well as $u\rightarrow -\infty.$ This means that we need u as negative as possible or positive as possible to select $\max_{u,t}|f_u|$. But which one?

Our domain in which we need the Lipschitz constant is $D=\{ (u,t): |u-a|<c;0 \leq t \leq a\}$ for some positive constant c. $f_u$ is a polymial as must be bounded on a closed ($D$).

I don't know what to make of all this? Please help me reach a conclusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I remarked on [the previous incarnation of this question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/37348/picard-lindel%c3%b6f-theorem-applied-on-an-ivp), if you reproduce the source correctly it should be $y(0)=a\gtrapprox 0$ for the time interval $[0,2/a]$ with a near vertical jump from zero to one expected at $t=1/a$. (Or to stay in that geometric setup, $y(0)=1/a$, $a\gg1$, on the interval $[0,2a]$.)

Your question has an easy answer:

- The right side is polynomial, thus locally Lipschitz, thus all solutions are unique on their domain.
- The right side $u^2-u^3=u^2(1-u)$ has roots at $u=0$ and $u=1$ which give constant equilibrium solutions. As the initial value is inside $(0,1)$, the solution under consideration is bounded by these constant solutions, thus can not diverge and so exists on the whole of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thank you very! I have studiet your statements carefully and they makes a sense. I only have one question: *"... is polynomial, thus locally Lipschitz".* Why is that? :)

Comment: Because the derivative is continuous, thus has maxima and minima over bounded intervals.